# Bug in gcc with const& template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, auto, non-type

Consider [this](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+int+%3E+struct+II+%7B+%7D%3B%0Atemplate+%3C+const+int%26+%3E+struct+RR+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+template+%3Cauto%3E+typename+Class,+typename+Type+%3E+struct+Check+:+std::false_type+%7B+%7D%3B%0Atemplate+%3C+template+%3Cauto%3E+typename+Class,+auto+NonTypes+%3E+struct+Check%3CClass,Class%3CNonTypes%3E%3E+:+std::true_type+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aconstexpr+int+TEN+%3D+10%3B%0Aconstexpr+const+int%26+REF+%3D+TEN%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(Check%3CII,II%3CTEN%3E%3E::value)%3B%0Astatic_assert(Check%3CRR,RR%3CREF%3E%3E::value)%3B%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g7snapshot,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7+(snapshot)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template < int > struct II { };
template < const int& > struct RR { };

template < template <auto> typename Class, typename Type > struct Check : std::false_type { };
template < template <auto> typename Class, auto NonTypes > struct Check<Class,Class<NonTypes>> : std::true_type { };

constexpr int TEN = 10;
constexpr const int& REF = TEN;

static_assert(Check<II,II<TEN>>::value); // passes
static_assert(Check<RR,RR<REF>>::value); // FAILS!?
```

I am using gcc-7.0.1 and [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,options:(colouriseAsm:'0',compileOnChange:'0'),source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+int+%3E+struct+II+%7B+%7D%3B%0Atemplate+%3C+const+int%26+%3E+struct+RR+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3C+template+%3Cauto%3E+typename+Class,+typename+Type+%3E+struct+Check+:+std::false_type+%7B+%7D%3B%0Atemplate+%3C+template+%3Cauto%3E+typename+Class,+auto+NonTypes+%3E+struct+Check%3CClass,Class%3CNonTypes%3E%3E+:+std::true_type+%7B+%7D%3B%0A%0Aconstexpr+int+TEN+%3D+10%3B%0Aconstexpr+const+int%26+REF+%3D+TEN%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(Check%3CII,II%3CTEN%3E%3E::value)%3B%0Astatic_assert(Check%3CRR,RR%3CREF%3E%3E::value)%3B%0A'),l:'5',n:'1',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g7snapshot,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7+(snapshot)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) is the live example. The question is if this is a compiler bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Just my guess: a plain `auto` (from `NonTypes`) can't deduce a reference type that would match `const int&` of what's deduced under `Class` (at least it works with `const auto& NonTypes`)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Wouldn't it then make sense that it would work with `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: @user975989 I think that matching a template specialization boils down to deducing types of an invented function template, where `decltype(auto)` is of no use

Answer (score 1):

Let's simplify the example a bit:

```
template <template <auto> class C, auto N>
void foo(C<N> ) { }

int main() {
    foo(II<TEN>{} ); // ok
    foo(RR<REF>{} ); // error
}
```

The problem is that the normal `auto` deduction rules apply for `N`, which gets deduced in the `REF` case to type `int`. There's a mismatch between the non-type template parameter type - `int const&` - and the argument - `int`, so it's ill-formed.

If we flipped the example to take `auto const& N` (or `auto&& N`) instead, then it'd be the `II<TEN>` call that would be ill-formed for the same reason - we'd now get a template argument of reference type but the parameter is a non-reference type.

You can't handle both cases with one function in the language today. You'd need two:

```
template <template <auto> class C, auto N>     void foo(C<N> ) { } // #1
template <template <auto&&> class C, auto&& N> void foo(C<N> ) { } // #2

int main() {
    foo(II<TEN>{} ); // ok: calls #1
    foo(RR<REF>{} ); // ok: calls #2
}
```

And similar for your original example: you'd need one specialization for values and one specialization for references. The reference in the template-template non-type parameter for `C` may not be necessary.